# What is the resulting Voltage Transfer characteristics of the modified CMOS-inverter circuit if NMOS and PMOS are interchanged?

Tags: cmos, nmos, vlsi, pmos

What is the resulting Voltage Transfer characteristics of the modified CMOS-inverter circuit, if the positions of \$NMOS\$ and \$PMOS\$ are interchanged?[image]

Comment: 1/ "the modified CMOS-inverter circuit" Which circuit? 2/ Sounds like homework or ( as the text is so short) a running exam question.

Comment: It is not a running exam question, I have come across many solutions online all of them suggest this structure to  be a weak buffer, but my analysis says otherwise: https://imgur.com/MlMyVNU . Can you please verify?

Answer (score 1):

Switch them and they're both acting as drain followers (like an emitter follower).  The circuit will stop inverting, but the output will not go closer to either rail than Vgs(th) unless pulled externally.  If the load has a significant bias current, it will be pulled to one rail by the bias current and driven within Vgs(th) of the other rail by the buffer.